# xunit.runners.1.9.2 - Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, xunit, microsoft-fakes

I am using `Xunit` test framework along with MS Fakes mocking framework within visual studio. It works fine when I run my tests within visual studio, but when I try to run my tests on build seerver using Xunit runner console or command line it fails with below error,

> **Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException:
>   Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and
>   COR_PROFILER environment variables.**

Answer (score 0):

Build server is not able to find the dll path. Try to add below entry in build server environment variable, user 
COR_ENABLE_PROFILING  1
COR_PROFILER {B7ABE522-A68F-44F2-925B-81E7488E9EC0}

Since you are using Fake Object, use can consider using VS Test from dll output directory:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /inIsolation YourTests.dll